# How to say "you may not [verb] here"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

たとえば、おすしを食べてもいいですか？ is for "May I eat sushi?".　However I know that ちょっと、食べなくてもいいです。Is not the right phrase because that means: "Well, you don't have to eat (that)." So what is the response for "[Sorry,] you *may **not*** eat sushi."?

**Afterthoughts** (after reading istraci, chocolate, and the two "users" responses).

Could you use this in response? おすしを食べることができません。

Also, one is this grammatically correct and two, is this saying what I think it means (you may not eat sushi)? おすしを食べてもよくないです。

Comment: Notice that in negation も changes to は.

Answer (score 9):

Some others that haven't been mentioned yet.  In first two that contain は, the は can be omitted depending on context and/or familiarity.

#### 〜て（は）ならない － somewhat strong; commanding

> - [犯罪]{はん・ざい}を[犯]{おか}してはならない　→　You must not commit any crimes
> - その[部屋]{へや}に[入]{はい}ってはならない　→　You cannot enter that room

#### 〜て（は）だめ － more casual/familiar, but still commanding

> - ポイ[捨]{す}てしちゃだめだよ！　→　Don't litter!  (しちゃ = しては)
> - 一人で行ってはだめ　→　You must not go by yourself
> - ここでタバコ[吸]{す}っては**アカン**！　→　You may not smoke here (アカン is Kansai-ben; from [明]{あ}かない)

**[遠慮]{えん・りょ}（する） － refrain from; a polite way to state a rule or preference**

> - [車内]{しゃない}での[通話]{つうわ}はご[遠慮]{えんりょ}ください　→　Please do not make calls inside the (train) car / Please refrain from making calls inside the (train) car
> - [機内]{きない}での[喫煙]{きつえん}はご遠慮[願]{ねが}います　→　You are requested to refrain from smoking inside the airplane.

**～[禁止]{きん・し}／[厳禁]{げん・きん} － often used on signs**

> - [立入禁止]{たち・いり・きん・し}　→　No entrance
> - [駐車禁止]{ちゅう・しゃ・きん・し}　→　No parking
> - [土足厳禁]{ど・そく・げん・きん}　→　"No shoes permitted"　→　Remove your shoes before entering

#### ～こと － used only in writing, such as notices, instructions, etc.

> - [感電]{かん・でん}のおそれがありますので、[手を[触]{ふ}れないこと](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/10977/78)　→　At the risk of being shocked, do not touch (Maybe the label on an electrical box)

Comment: ?? My edit was cancelled for some reason...(T_T)

Comment: I was adding to my original answer, and I must have clicked "Update" a few seconds after you did.  You can re-edit it if you wish.  ごめん、ねっ！

Comment: @Chocolate:  forgot to tag you in my previous comment so that you'd see it.

Comment: Ah I see, nvm~ (ここでタバコ吸ったらアカン or ここでタバコ吸うたらアカン might be more natural... 吸うたら is Kansai-ben, like [買]{こ}うたら for [買]{か}ったら, もうたら for もらったら, [会]{お}うたら for [会]{あ}ったら etc...)

Comment: (Ah the question was modified and a further question was added-- but are the answerers not notified? I still don't know much about the system here)

Comment: @Chocolate I thought that those who have responded to the thread would be notified automatically of the changes. ごめんなさい。However if you have any answers or comments to my new questions, I'd be happy to receive them.

Comment: I was not notified when the question changed.  Only when someone added comments to my answer.

Comment: It is very important to mention the -な verbs, since they are used very often. For example you often see 触るな! signs on a pipes which are hot and can cause burns.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the strength of the interdiction, you can answer:

- すしは食べないでください　"Please do not eat sushi" (plain negative form + でください)
- すしは食べてはいけません　"It's forbidden to eat sushi" (て form + は + いけません)

Comment: There is also, 申し訳ございませんが、ここでは食事が禁止されております。 or …ここでは食べられません or …ここでは食べられないことになっています。

Answer (score 2):

(I'm responding to your afterthoughts)

> おすしを食べてもいいですか？
>   Could you use this in response? おすしを食べることができません。

I think you could say:
お寿司 **は** 食べることができません。
お寿司を食べること **は** できません。
お寿司 **は** 食べられません。
or お寿司 **は** 食べること **は** できません。etc.
... using the binding particle は somewhere.

> おすしを食べてもよくないです。
>  
>   one-- is this grammatically correct?
>  
>   two-- is this saying what I think it means (you may not eat sushi)?

1-- No
2-- Hm, if I heard you say that I'd think you meant it... (^_^;)
I think you could say more like:
お寿司は食べてはいけません。
お寿司を食べてはいけません。
(I think "お寿司 **は**・・・" would sound more natural as a response to お寿司~~~ですか？)